# Converting CLOB to String removes all new line characters

Tags: java, string, h2, java-11, clob

I have an H2 database with AES encryption enabled. It has a column of type CLOB. The column contains long texts with new line characters(some times). When I check the table in H2 console I get outputs with all the new lines inserted but when I query the table, there are no new line characters. I am using this code to convert a CLOB object to String object:

```
public String clobToString(Clob data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Reader reader = data.getCharacterStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;
        while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I think something is going here. Is there any other efficient way of doing this CLOB to String conversion.

Comment: Of course it removes all new line characters, because the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) says: *"Returns a String containing the contents of the line, **not including any line-termination characters**, or null if the end of the stream has been reached"*.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this so that I get a string with all the newline characters?...

Comment: `sb.append(line).append("\r\n");`

Comment: @Andreas strange but every example till now, appends without new line, and has the same suboptimal conversion of Clob.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yeah, I saw that when trying to look for a duplicate, so I decided to write a [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777729/5221149).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a `String` value from a `CLOB` column in the database, use one of the following:

- Use [`resultSet.getString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString-java.lang.String-):

  ```java
  String text = resultSet.getString("MyClobColumn");
  ```
- If the data is already taken from the `ResultSet` as a [`Clob`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html) (using `getClob()`), use [`clob.getSubString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getSubString-long-int-):

  ```java
  String text = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
  ```
- If you for some obscure reason have a `Reader` (from [`resultSet.getCharacterStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getCharacterStream-java.lang.String-) or [`clob.getCharacterStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getCharacterStream--)), copy the characters in blocks, and remember to use try-with-resources, e.g.

  ```java
  String text;
  try (Reader reader = clob.getCharacterStream()) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      char[] buf = new char[8192];
      for (int len; (len = reader.read(buf)) != -1; )
          sb.append(line, 0, len);
      text = sb.toString();
  }
  ```

  Or with Java 10+:

  ```java
  String text;
  try (Reader reader = clob.getCharacterStream()) {
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      reader.transferTo(sw);
      text = sw.toString();
  }
  ```

All three of course assumes that the text will fit in a `String`, i.e. that it is less than about 2.1 billion characters, or only about 1 billion characters depending on Java version and characters used (non-Latin1).

Comment: When you have a `Reader`, you might be better off using `StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); reader.transferTo(sw); text = sw.toString();`. Btw, with Java 9+, the length limit is much lower when the string contains characters not representable in ISO-LATIN-1.